# How to include a newline in the python raw_input() function?

Tags: python, console-application

I'm using `raw_input()` to storing a message inside a variable. So I can't press enter for a carriage return/new line to start a new paragraph. Right now if I press enter it will just proceed to the next portion of my program.

I already tried something like this:

```
>>> message = raw_input("Message: ")
Message: Hello Sir, \n It's great that..
>>> message
"Hello Sir, \\n It's great that.."
>>>
```

It didn't worked, and I also tried enclosing it in single and double quotes, which also didn't worked.

I understand that there are other ways of doing this, like using *wxpython* or *tkinter*, but I want to keep it strictly console. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you use the `sys` module? This will do the trick if you want. Just hit Ctrl-D to end it.

```
import sys
message = sys.stdin.readlines()
```

Otherwise, this answers your question: [Python raw_input ignore newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047349/python-raw-input-ignore-newline)

Comment: sys.stdin.readlines() works like a charm, but i can't seem to get ctrl-d to work i don't know why?

Comment: i figured it out, i have to use ctrl-c instead, but now i get a keyboard interrupt error if i tried to print the message.

Comment: I figured it out finally! I can't use ctrl-c, that's what makes the keyboard interrupt error, and I can't use ctrl-d because i'm on windows, i have to use ctrl-z or f6 and then it will display in the console like this ^Z and press enter. after that i have to convert the message from a list back into a string, which i manage to do like this >>>roughmessage = sys.stdin.readlines()
>>>message = ''.join(roughmessage)