# Python how to read lines and how to output the new lines

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

So I've looked on stackoverflow for this, the only one I got to kinda work was,

```
buffer = ''
while True:
    line = raw_input()
    if not line: break

    buffer += line
print(buffer)
```

but, it didn't print it out like how I pasted it (with lines) instead, it did it all in one line.

Any idea how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Replace `buffer += line` with `buffer += '\n' + line`.

Comment: Post as answer, it worked thanks!

Comment: Look at the following [Python raw_input ignore newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047349/python-raw-input-ignore-newline) and [How to include a newline in the python raw_input() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238085/how-to-include-a-newline-in-the-python-raw-input-function). you can harness, `sys.stdin.readlines` for this purpose.

Comment: And keep in mind, variable `buffer` grows in size as you read more lines which may not be efficient if you're willing to process a massive amount of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
buffer = ''
while True:
    line = raw_input()
    if not line: break

    buffer += '\n' + line
print(buffer)
```

That works as below:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Salam
Hi
Salut


Salam
Hi
Salut
>>>
```

As you see above, I placed a `\n` in the line of `buffer += '\n' + line`. This character is named *new line* escape character. The interpreter relace it with a new line.

The other way is using `list` as below:

```
mylist = list()

while True:
    line = raw_input()
    if not line: break
    mylist.append(line)

for line in mylist:
    print(line)
```

Using above methodology, I stored each line as a member of `mylist` and at the end I printed those members one by one.

Answer (score 1):

```
buffer = ''

while True:
    line = raw_input()
    if not line: break

    buffer += line+ "\n"

print(buffer)
```

There you go, its crude but it works fine...